# Referencing 'Version' Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, flow, version, json-formatting

[image]

Hi there,

I am relatively new to using SharePoint as well as JSON and as mentioned in the subject, I am having issues in trying to reference the Version column (set by the approval status).

What I hope to achieve is such that if the "version" number is the same as the "version flow" number, a conditional formatting would be set to show a green background and red if the version flow number is less than the version number.

I have hard coded the values of 13 just to see if I could get the colours to appear. Whenever I try to reference [$Version], the values in version flow would disappear. Help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

I have attached my current code applied to th 'Version Flow' column as conditional formatting.

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {},
  "style": {
    "background-color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": ">=",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            "13.0"
          ]
        },
        "#98FB98",
        {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "<",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField",
                "13.0"
              ]
            },
            "#FF6A6A",
            ""
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "customRowAction": {},
  "children": []
}
```

Comment: Also, you are saying `What I hope to achieve is such that if the "version" number is the same as the "version flow" number` and you are checking the condition for greater than or equal to in your first condition. check this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It's actually another issue that I have yet to resolve. Strangely when say for example, version = 15.1 and version flow = 15.1, when I set the condtion operator to "==", the condition result is false. Any idea why> =

Comment: What is the data type of Version flow field?

Comment: I just found my error thanks to your question! Version flow was originally of number type. I changed it to string and now it works.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, assuming if I were to apply this conditional formatting to the row, version flow instead (i.e. compare version flow with version instead of the other way around), what should I use instead of [$_UIVersionString] ? Another issue that I realised was that my code causes the cell text to be top aligned. Is there any way to centralize it while still keeping the background colour changes?

Comment: This is something related to CSS part. you can achieve this by some style manipulation. try using `"display": "table-cell",
    "text-align": "center",
    "vertical-align": "middle"` in style property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `[$Version]`, use **`[$_UIVersionString]`**.

So, your code should be something like below:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {},
  "style": {
    "background-color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": ">=",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            [$_UIVersionString]
          ]
        },
        "#98FB98",
        {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "<",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField",
                [$_UIVersionString]
              ]
            },
            "#FF6A6A",
            ""
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "customRowAction": {},
  "children": []
}
```

**Note**: `Version` is a Single line of text field.

Comment: Try above code and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much Ganesh.